# Sending c# string to c++ server through network

Tags: c#, c++, networking

I'm writing a c# client who need to communicate with a c++ server. I'm trying to find a way to send a string to the server, and i'm stuck, since a char in c# is 2 bytes and in c++ it's 1.

How can I convert my strings to send them as a readable char array for the server?

Thanks a lot!

Ps : I will have the same problem with other types like int and stuff I think.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use `std::wstring` which is wide character and of two bytes.

Comment: I can't touch the server side :/

Comment: If your C# char's are under ascii range (sure size is 2 bytes), but if they come under ascii range, you can send byte. So for ascii byte and char are same.

Comment: Ok so the sizeof(char) = 2 is just the "sure" size? If I convert my string, saying a four characters, into a byte array, the byte array will be of a length of 4 in any cases? (Yes all my characters will be in ascii range)

Comment: @AlbanBecquet Yes, because all ascii range is under 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easy convert your string to an ascii byte array before sending it to the server:

```
string message = ...
byte [] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
server.Send(data);
```

Be sure however that you send messsages that consist of characters covered in the ascii-table. Characters outside that table can bring some surprises when converted to ascii.

Converting the received answer from the server back into a string

```
byte [] received = ...
string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, sending data from client to server and back through *some kind of connection* is not the easiest thing to do.
I can share my experience, in which I need to serialize properties of serializable classes into stream of bytes to be sent across a *generic connection*.

Using the `System.BitConverter` you can get the representation of basic data types (bool, char, double, float, ...) into arrays of bytes:

```
byte[] f1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(MsgID); // MsgID is a ulong
```

for `string` objects you could use the UTF8 encoding:

```
// == Payload is a C# string ==
// calculates how many bytes we need to stream the Payload
payloadBufferSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(Payload);
// create a suitable buffer
payloadBuffer = new byte[payloadBufferSize];
// Encode the Payload in the buffer
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Payload, 0, Payload.Length, payloadBuffer, 0);
```

doing so you have an array of bytes you can send through your connection, given that on the other side you have some kind of object that is able to decode an UTF8 stream of bytes.

If you just want to get a plain ASCII stream, you could use the `Encoding.ASCII` encoder instead of the `Encoding.UTF8` in the sample above, but if you have unicode character you'll get a '?' as a resulting char.